# multiple rewrites nginx

Tags: nginx

I currently have my URL for my video page rewritten like so

```
rewrite ^/watch/(.*) /video.php?vid_id=$1 last;
```

This makes the URL look like

```
www.site.com/watch/123456
```

instead of

```
www.site.com/video.php?vid_id=123456
```

I want to be able to add the title in the URL like so without it affecting the location and current behavior of the URL above

```
www.site.com/watch/123456/vid-title
```

I would also however, like to be able to still use `www.site.com/watch/123456` or www.site.com/watch/123456/ to get to my video and therefore be equivalent to my original URL (have flexibility in the URL). **Does anyone know how to do this with NGINX? Do I need multiple rewrites? I have tried combinations of multiple rewrites with no success. I have seen it done on many sites but am not sure how they accomplished it.**

Comment: What URL you want to rewrite `www.site.com/watch/123456/vid-title` to?

Comment: I want it to go to `www.site.com/video.php?vid_id=123456`. I do not want the title add-on to affect my current url position of `www.site.com/watch/123456`. I just want the title added on for search engine optimization but I would also like the URL `www.site.com/watch/123456` to work without the title added on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
rewrite ^/watch/([^/]+)/?(?:vid-title)?$ /video.php?vid_id=$1 last;
```

- `([^/]+)` matches any number of characters but not slash. You can use
  `([0-9]+)` if you want.
- The question mask `?` makes the preceding regex is optional.
- `?:` tells the regex engine that this group should not create a
  backreference

Comment: You're the best quanta! Thanks so much for taking the time to help me out! How do you make vid-title a regex for any combination of this-is-my-title? Currently when I enter www.site.com/watch/123456/vid-title the url works but not if I enter www.site.com/watch/123456/some-other-vid-title

Comment: If your `vid-title` doesn't follow rules, you can use something like this `^/watch/([^/]+)/?(?:[^/]+)?/?$`.